# Not able to copy text from DhtmlxGrid in both chrome and mozilla firefox browser

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox, dhtml

Not able to copy text from DhtmlxGrid in  both chrome and mozilla firefox browser.
1) myGrid.enableBlockSelection(true); it is working fine for selecting the cells.

2) 
But bellow code not able to coping (cells data) from DhtmlxGrid 
myGrid.cellToClipboard();
Please any one help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the bellow solution.It's working fine.
myGrid.entBox.onselectstart = function(){ return true; };